# montar um arquivo json no client-side ou server-side?

Tags: javascript, json

o arquivo .json que estou desenvolvendo está inteiramente sendo montado no client-side, isso é uma boa prática?
uma parte do código:

```
                array.form[array.form.length - 1].perg.push({
                    numerodaperguntaSemPonto: retiraPonto(numeroDaPergunta[0].value),
                    descricaoQuestao: descricaoQuestao[0].value,
                    notapergunta: questao[0].value,
                    titleSub: [],
                    isObrig: false
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Depende,

1. Se o arquivo for baixado pelo usuario: não tem problema nenhum, só tome cuidado: se ele for importado, é bom você fazer uma verificação por segurança.
2. Se o JSON for enviado para um servidor, faça a verificação do lado do servidor, pode ser muito fácil de manipular esses dados na hora da requisição